# Updating a datatable cell in a dataset in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, datatable, dataset

In my C# MVC application, I have a dataset that is returned by a model.  Before iterating through the data on the view, I want to the cells of a particular column for, say matched text to be replaced.

Is the best place to do this before returning the dataset to the controller, or let the controller update the dataset.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some more details could change my mind. But probably not. Controller should already receive it modified.